# A "direct proof" that $\mathrm{Spa}(A,A^+)$ is quasicompact?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

When Huber introduces affinoid rings in his paper titled Continuous Valuations, he shows that for an affinoid ring $(A,A^+)$, now more commonly called a Huber pair, the spectrum $\mathrm{Spa}(A,A^+)$ is spectral, and quasicompactness follows. He does the former in (approximately) the following steps:

(i) show that $\mathrm{Spv}(A)$ is spectral for any ring $A$,

(ii) show that $\mathrm{Spv}(A,I)$ is spectral for certain ideals $I$, by showing it is a pro-constructible subset of $\mathrm{Spv}(A)$,

(iii) show that $\mathrm{Spa}(A,A^+)$ is a pro-constructible subset of $\mathrm{Spv}(A,I)$ where $I$ is the ideal in $A$ generated by topologically nilpotent elements.

I'm wondering if anybody knows of a more direct way to show the quasicompactness of $\mathrm{Spa}(A,A^+)$, if one didn't want to define the spaces $\mathrm{Spv}(A)$ and $\mathrm{Spv}(A,I)$? Possibly even avoiding arguments involving constructible subsets (though this seems less likely)?

Comment: It seems unlikely, but it may also not be worth much effort to find such a proof since a lot of the power of adic spaces over other approaches to non-archimedean geometry (in the context of recent activity) rests on the spectrality property and not merely quasi-compactness.